Is there a Lie group operator for conjugate of a complex column matrix?
Let's say one has a general $2\times1$ complex column matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha+\beta i \\ \theta+\lambda i \end{pmatrix}$. Is there a Lie group whose elements can be used for complex conjugating (and swapping rows) of the above column matrix? In other words, for changing the above column matrix to:  $\begin{pmatrix} \theta-\lambda i  \\ \alpha-\beta i \end{pmatrix}$. Would elements of the group SO(2) can be used for this transformation?
From the comments . . .
I was thinking that it would be possible to find a $2\times2$ matrix to make such transformation since one would need to solve a system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns. But I wasn't sure if that $2\times2$ matrix in the general case could be written in terms of elements of SO(2).

You need a $4 \times 4$ real matrix. A $2 \times 2$ complex matrix acting on complex vectors in the obvious way can only produce complex-linear transformations, and conjugation isn't complex-linear.

Can you put complex conjugation as an element in a group? Yes, easily. Is this a Lie group action on $\mathbb{C}^2$? Sort of.
The first point is that complex conjugation is an invertible (indeed self-inverse) operation. Denoting it by $\sigma$, say, your group could simply be $\{\mathrm{id}, \sigma\}$. You could replace $\sigma$ by the swap the rows and then complex conjugate operation as well. Or you could even denote swapping rows (a.k.a. reflection in $x=y$) by $\tau$ and make the group $\{\mathrm{id}, \sigma,\tau, \tau\sigma\}$. These are all finite discrete groups and so are $0$-dimensional Lie groups.
The problem is conjugation isn't complex linear so this action is not a complex Lie group representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$. Indeed this means any complex representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ cannot include conjugation.
You could instead view $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then complex conjugation is a real linear function so this would work. For example if $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}i \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$ are represented as $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ then complex conjugation is simply $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0 \\ 0&-1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and "swapping rows" while conjugating is $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-1 \\1&0&0&0 \\ 0&-1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$.
Careful here as it is now a little unclear what we mean by rows as we have converted to a real vector space underlying the complex one.
So the answer is technically yes, but I think this is not quite what you may be imagining and we have to abandon the complex structure to make this work

"Not a Lie group representation" is a strange way to put it. It's not a complex representation, but it is a real one.

@QiaochuYuan I would argue it is not a representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$. It is a representation on $\mathbb{R}^4$ which might be the same underlying set but is different as a vector space.

@QiaochuYuan Either way I'm probably not making myself clear so I've edited my answer
